# Proving if Boolean Equations are valid

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I need to prove algebraically that:

$$ab + abc'd + abde' + abc'e + a'b = b$$

$$(wxyz)(wxyz' + wx'yz + w'xyz + wxy'z) = 0$$

Comment: I do not know how to do this. I need to see this completed for me to fully grasp the concept. It is just the way I learn.

Comment: No it doesn't. I really need to see an answer for this fast! It would be greatly appreciate

Answer (score 1):

> $$ab + abc'd + abde' + abc'e + a'b = b\tag{1}$$

\begin{align} ab + abc'd +abde' + abc'e + a'b 
& = b(\color{blue}{\bf a} + ac'd + ade' + ac'e + \color{blue}{\bf a'}) \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\tag{distributive rule}\\ \\
& = b(\color{blue}{\bf 1} + a(c'd + de' + c'e)) \tag{$\color{blue}{\bf a + a' = 1}$}\\ \\
& = b\cdot 1\tag{why?}\\ \\
& = b \tag{why?}
\end{align}

> $$(wxyz) * (wxyz' + wx'yz + w'xyz + wxy'z) = 0\tag{2}$$

\begin{align} & (wxyz) * (wxyz' + wx'yz + w'xyz + wxy'z) \\ \\
& = wxyzwxyz' + wxyzwx'yz + wxyzw'xyz + wxyzwxy'z \\ \\
& = wxy(zz') + w(xx')yz + (ww')xyz + wx(yy')z \tag{why?}\\ \\
& = wxy\cdot 0 + wyz\cdot 0 + 0 \cdot xyz + wxz\cdot 0 \tag{why?}\\ \\
& = 0 
\end{align}

---

Here we need

- the distributive rule,
- the identities

  - $\;0\cdot a = 0$,
  - $1 + a = 1$, and
- absorption:

  - $aa = a$,
  - $a+a = a$.

These are crucial to know, on the spot, as is DeMorgan's, which was not needed in either problem.

Comment: Amazing answer. Thanks so much. Could I get help with the second part too? :)

Comment: Nice Amy. :^+).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint for the first one**: Note that $$ab+abc'd+abde'+abc'e+a'b = ab(1+c'd+de'+c'e)+a'b$$ and that $$ab+a'b=(a+a')b=1*b=b.$$ What is $1+x$ for any $x$ in the boolean algebra?

---

**Hint for the second one**: Note that, for example, $$wxyz*wxyz'=wwxxyyzz'=wxyzz'=wxy*0=0,$$ and use distributivity.